# Address a specific slide in RhinoSlider via URL

Tags: jquery

Do you know if there's a way to navigate through slides in **RhinoSlider** ([rhinoslider.com](http://rhinoslider.com)) via external links? There probably is, as all want to do is substitute the nav bullets. I just don't know how are specific slides accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<a onclick="$('#slider').data('rhinoslider').next($('#rhino-item2')); return false;">Go to 3 slide</a>
```

where `rhino-item2` is id of LI slide element in #slider (or whatever your slider id)

**UPDATE:**
I've found that slider stuck on double link click, so the solution is to check if trying to select already choosen slide:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rgo(id)
{
    var cur_id = $('#slider').find('li.rhino-active').index();

    if (cur_id!=id)
        $('#slider').data('rhinoslider').next($('#rhino-item'+id));

    return false;
}
</script>

<a onclick="return rgo(2)">Go to 3 slide</a>
```